# React Native Firebase auth working on Android but not IOS device / simulator

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native

My project is Expo managed. The auth and login are working completely fine when I test it on the web browser and Android. But when I use a physical device or IOS simulator, it doesn't work.

signInWithEmailAndPassword() won't return anything but timeout and then the app crash. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't used react native for a long time, but I remember that you need to make settings on debug.key, firebase's site and developers.google.com.